# QtListView Line Numbers

Tags: python, qt, pyside

Is there a way to append line numbers to a QListView widget, i know you can add text using
setText() but it only except a str not an integer, so I can't just increment an integer and print it.  Any ideas?

here is the code:

```
with open("../content/vulcan.hosts") as new_file:
            reader = csv.reader(new_file, delimiter='|')
            for line in reader:
                i = 1
                uname = line[0]
                iface = line[1]
                macad = line[2]
                ipad  = line[3]
                type  = line[4]
                item = QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem()
                item.setFlags(QtCore.Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable)
                item.setCheckState(0, QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)
                item.setText(0, str(i))
                i = 1 + 1
                item.setText(1, uname)
                item.setText(2, iface)
                item.setText(3, macad)
                item.setText(4, ipad)
                item.setText(5, type)
                item.setText(6, str("asdasd"))
                item.setText(7, str("asdasda"))
                item.setText(8, str("asdasd"))
                self.runTree.addTopLevelItem(item)
```

Comment: You can convert `int`s to strings via `str(i)`.

Comment: Can you provide a bit more code showing what you have tried?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add it to the item's text, you can simply use one of Qt's ways to convert an integer to a string. There is for example the static [`number(...)`](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qstring.html#number) set of methods.

```
int a = 63;
QString s = QString.number(a); // s == "63"
```

I'm not exactly sure what kind of data you're working with however, but perhaps a QListView is not the best option for you. Have you thought about a QTableView/Widget? There you could add some decent row numbering.